# How to split string with "-" as delimiter

Tags: r, string

I tried to split string using "-" as delimiter.
But why this doesn't work:

```
> stringr::str_split("158–170", "-")
[[1]]
[1] "158–170"

> strsplit("158–170", "-")
[[1]]
[1] "158–170"
```

I expect the output to be vector of two strings `"158"` and `"170"`.

Comment: Looks like an "em dash" and not an "en dash"

Comment: If all strings look like that, then replace your `"-"` with the character found in the string itself, i.e., `"–"`. If you think you may have both, though, you can always do `stringr::str_split("158–170", "[-–]")`, which will work with *that* "em dash" as well as (what I think of as) normal "en dash". (Note that the "en dash" is first and must be first in that bracket class, the "em dash" is second.)

Comment: To clarify, the dash in your string is an "en dash" (U+2013), the dash in the pattern is a "hyphen/minus" (U+002D).  An "em dash" is another character (U+2014) longer than the "en dash" and not present in either your string or pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the dash you have put in your string is longer than the split one (not sure how that's happened). I have replaced them below , please try:

```
strsplit("158-170", "-")
```